# Error: uninitialized constant Guard::Haml::Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, guard, compass

I am using `guard` with `guard-haml` and trying to write a `RoR` like `render` function that I can use in my `haml` templates.

My error is `Error: uninitialized constant Guard::Haml::Engine`

My Guardfile is:

```
# guard-haml: watch haml files in src/haml and compile to dist/
guard :haml, output: 'dist', input: 'src/haml', run_at_start: true, helper_modules: 'Helpers' do
    watch %r{^src/.+(\.html\.haml)}
end

# helpers
module ::Haml::Helpers
    def render(partial)
        Haml::Engine.new(File.read("./src/haml/_#{partial}.haml")).render
    end
end
```

I have a partial `_head.haml` and in my `index.haml` I have:

```
=render :head
%body
    %h1 Hello, World!
```

Not sure what to do. Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `Haml::Engine` to this `::Haml::Engine`. Possible the code in `#render` is executed in `Guard`'s namespace and makes the constant lookup to search for `Guard::Haml:Engine`, not `Object::Haml::Engine`.

[More on constant lookup in ruby](http://valve.github.io/blog/2013/10/26/constant-resolution-in-ruby/).